# How to let hibernate create TIMESTAMP that is not autogenerated?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

How can I prevent generation of attribute timestamp extension `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`?

I simply want to set the timestamp myself, and not let the database update or create the timestamp?

```
@Entity
public class MyEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public long id;

    public LocalDateTime created_at;
}

CREATE TABLE `price_tracker` (
  id bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  created_at timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Comment: is this mysql ?

Comment: @membersound What hibernate dialect do you use?

Comment: I'm using latest `spring-boot` and `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update` with mysql. Not sure, how can I see the dialect? Probably it's `MySQL8Dialect`

Answer (score 0):

Got rid of it as follows:

```
@Column(updatable = false,
        columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP(2)")
public LocalDateTime created_at;
```